# If I learn Persian/Farsi, could I be able to understand Uighur language?

Tags: persian, turkic-languages

Ok, someone once told me that Uighur is a Turkic langugage. But just wondering, for Persian and Uighur, the two, Are they similar in any way? or just helps a little bit? Could one understand another?

Answer (score 10):

No.

Your friend is right about Uighur being Turkic. But Persian is not Turkic; it's Indo-European, so lexical similarity between these languages is going to be VERY low and limited to a few loan-words. From what I can tell, the only thing that's similar is the alphabet, both having been derived from Arabic.

Comment: Ok good to know....

Comment: I guess the confusion comes from the terminology in e.g. Wikipedia which states that the writing system is ["derived from Perso-Arabic"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uyghur_Arabic_alphabet). But this indeed only pertains to the symbols used in writing. Similarly, an English speaker has no chance to decipher written Basque or Finnish, even though the symbols used to write those languages are familiar.

Comment: "VERY low" and "a few loan-words" is not correct. Both Persian and Uighur have a VERY large number of Arabic loans, and Uighur also has a lot of loans from Persian.

Comment: @fdb enough that OP will understand Uighur from learning Farsi?

Comment: No, but s/he will probably be able to pick out a lot of words.

Comment: @fdb Feel free to answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to influence of other Turkic languages, Uyghur has historically been influenced strongly by Arabic and Persian and more recently by Russian and Mandarin Chinese.

But as a Persian, even I can't Understand what they say ... :) so the answer No

All the best

Comment: But Persian is a language that you would never regret learning.

Omar Khaymam, Hafez, saadi, .... wonderful people that anybody needs to know

Answer (score 0):

In general, learning both Persian, AND A Turkic language will help you in understanding Uyghur a lot. But if you had to pick one to help you understand Uyghur the quickest, pick the Turkic language.

As an Iranian Azerbaijani person, I feel that I understand more of Uyghur than Turkish people (from Turkey) could, especially when it comes to poetry and songs. And this is due to my knowledge of Persian and Persian literature. But if we travelled back to the Ottoman times, maybe Ottoman Turkish would have been just as efficient as my Azerbaijani, due to the large portion of Persian used in Ottoman Turkish.

P.S. If Iranian Azerbaijani confuses you, just google it ;)